# Create same type ArrayList as ArrayList parameter in method

Tags: java, generics

I'm implementing mergesort in Java. I want it to work with every object that can be compared.

Here's code

```
public class MergeSort
{
    public static void sort(ArrayList<? extends Comparable> list)
    {
        mergesort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
    }

    private static void mergesort(ArrayList<? extends Comparable> list, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start >= end)
            return;

        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        mergesort(list, start, mid);
        mergesort(list, mid + 1, end);
        merge(list, start, mid, end);
    }

    private static void merge(ArrayList<? extends Comparable> list, int start, int mid, int end)
    {
        ArrayList<? extends Comparable> temp = new ArrayList<Comparable>(end - start + 1);
        int j = mid + 1;
        for (int i = start; i <= mid; i++)
        {
            while (j <= end && list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(j)) > 0)
            {
                temp.add(list.get(j));
                j++;
            }
            temp.add(list.get(i));
        }
        while (j <= end)
        {
            temp.add(list.get(j));
            j++;
        }

        int j = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            list.set(i, temp.get(j));
            j++;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't add elements to "temp" array, compiler says that I should change temp to Comparable, but then I can't replace elements from "temp" to "list".
I understand that compiler thinks that list might be Integers and temp Floats. How can I set "temp" to be same type as "list"?

Comment: What's the signature of Collections.sort()? You should have the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic type parameter:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    mergesort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
}
```

and

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void mergesort(List<T> list, int start, int end) {
...
```

and

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void merge(List<T> list, int start, int mid, int end) {
    ArrayList<T> temp = new ArrayList<T>(end - start + 1);
...
```

---

**Edit:**

To achieve the most flexibility you can replace `<T extends Comparable<T>>` with `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

This would for example allow to pass in a list of elements of class `Foo` with `Foo` implementing `Comparable<Object>`. Additionally your function would have the same signature as `Collections.sort` as suggested in a comment.

Comment: I feel stupid now. I used generics maybe once. Thanks for clearing that out.

Answer (score -2):

You can declare all your lists like: `ArrayList<Comparable>`. The compiler will not complain anymore and will work as you intended.

And then, you have an `int j` declared twice. :)

Comment: *compiler says that I should change temp to Comparable, but then I can't replace elements from "temp" to "list"*

Comment: I haven't thought of changing all Arrays. I checked that solution and you can't pass ArrayList<Integer> to sort(ArrayList<Comparable> list)